# SQL using sum(days)

Tags: sql

My question is in regards to using a function sum(days) and reusing it within my query.

```
select
  new_client, 
  sum(days) as effort
from actuals
where week >='01/01/2016' 
  and type is null 
  and sum(days) = 0
group by new_client
order by effort desc
```

I know this doesn't work. I was wondering how one would do the above.

Comment: Show us some sample table data, and the expected result (as formatted text)

Comment: what do you mean by reusing ?

Comment: What's in days field?

Comment: also tag the relevant DBMS you are using

Comment: Instead of using this in your where clause, use HAVING SUM(days) = 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select new_client, sum(days) as effort
from actuals
where week >='01/01/2016' and type is null                          
group by new_client
having sum(days) = 0
order by effort desc
```

Something like this should work? You can't use SUM() in your where clause. That's why HAVING exists.

Question is why you would want that SUM(days) in your select then, because it would always show 0 if there are results.

Comment: thank you jens. even in my crappy  attempt to ask the question you pulled thru.

Answer (score 1):

If `days` is never negative, you could also do:

```
select new_client, sum(days) as effort
from actuals
where week >= '2016-01-01' and type is null and days > 0
group by new_client
order by effort desc;
```

This is more efficient, because it does the filtering before the aggregation.  But @Jens answer is more general.

Answer (score 1):

Hi,
 Very nice question
You can use below query

```
select new_client, sum(days) as effort
from actuals
where week >='01/01/2016' and type is null
group by new_client
having  sum(days) = 0
order by effort desc
```

> Explination

WHERE clause executes the current condition while HAVING clause executed once all the conditions are executed. i.e. HAVING executes for the result of the condition and WHERE executes or process data row by row. In a simple way WHERE clause is a pre filter and HAVING clause is a post filter